# Array and slice data types

Tags: arrays, go, slice, pass-by-value, func

I found myself confused with the `array` and `slice` data types.

From Go docs, arrays are described as follows:

> There are major differences between the ways arrays work in Go and C. In Go,
>
> - Arrays are values. Assigning one array to another copies all the elements.
> - In particular, if you pass an array to a function, it will receive a copy of the array, not a pointer to it.
> - The size of an array is part of its type. The types [10]int and [20]int are distinct.

Functions:

> As in all languages in the C family, everything in Go is passed by
>   value. That is, a function always gets a copy of the thing being
>   passed, as if there were an assignment statement assigning the value
>   to the parameter. For instance, passing an int value to a function
>   makes a copy of the int, and passing a pointer value makes a copy of
>   the pointer, but not the data it points to.

Why does `sort.Ints(arrayValue)` modify the passed variable when I declared it as an array, not as a slice?

Code

```
var av = []int{1,5,2,3,7}

fmt.Println(av)
sort.Ints(av)
fmt.Println(av)
return
```

Output

```
[1 5 2 3 7]
[1 2 3 5 7]
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

See "[Slices: usage and internals](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html)"

```
var av = []int{1,5,2,3,7}
```

That is a slice, not an array.

> A slice literal is declared just like an array literal, except you leave out the element count.

That explains why the sort function will modify the *content* of what is referenced by the slice.

As commented below by [Kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236394/kirk), [`sort.Ints`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints)  will give you an error if you passed it an array instead of a slice.

```
func Ints(a []int)
```

Comment: In addition, sort.Ints will give you an error if you passed it an array instead of a slice. Documentation for sort.Ints specifies a slice. https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints

Comment: @Kirk good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 55):

Because you're using a slice, not an array.

That is a slice:

```
var av = []int{1,5,2,3,7}
```

And those are arrays:

```
var av = [...]int{1,5,2,3,7}
var bv = [5]int{1,5,2,3,7}
```

If you try to compile:

```
var av = [...]int{1,5,2,3,7}
fmt.Println(av)
sort.Ints(av)
fmt.Println(av)
```

, you will get an error:

> cannot use av (type [5]int) as type []int in function argument

as sort.Ints expects to receive a [slice []int](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Ints).

Comment: so, a slice is like an array "reference"?

Comment: yes, a slice consists of a pointer to an array element and a length. So it's a reference to a sub-section of the array (a 'slice' of the array if you will).

Comment: @mfhholmes thank you. This is the most concise explanation IMHO.

Comment: To add more to @mfhhomles' comment, here's a detailed golang post on the slice vs array concept: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 11):

`[]int{1,5,2,3,7}` is not an array. An array has it's length in it's type, like `[5]int{1,5,2,3,7}`.

Make a copy of the slice and sort it instead:

```
a := []int{1,5,2,3,7}
sortedA := make([]int, len(a))
copy(sortedA, a)
sort.Ints(sortedA)
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(sortedA)
```

Comment: It may also have ... instead of its length. [...]int{1,2,3}

Comment: @ArtemShitov Right, it's an helpful syntactic sugar. The compiler will translate it to `[3]int{1,2,3}` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

slices are pointer to array . when you copy an array to another or when you pass a array in the function the entire copy of array is copied or passed . This makes a costlier operation if thae array size is large. so we can go for slices.

Comment: This is the most sensible summary that I've seen on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

```
var av = []int{1,5,2,3,7}
```

in the above statement you are initializing slice like an array

To create an array the syntax should be

```
var av = [5]int{1,5,2,3,7}
```