# How to print a byte array as binary in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, binary

How to print a byte array `[]byte{255, 253}` as binary in Golang?

I.e.

```
[]byte{255, 253} --> 1111111111111101
```

Comment: By the way, that's a slice, not an array. In Go an array is an actual datatype different from slice and not just some vague list-like thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11737218/242457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmt.Printf` can print slices and arrays and applies the format to the elements of the array. This avoids the loop and gets us remarkably close:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    bs := []byte{0xff, 0xfd}
    fmt.Printf("%08b\n", bs) // prints [11111111 11111101]
}
```

Playground with above code: https://go.dev/play/p/8RjBJFFI4vf

The extra brackets (which are part of the slice notation) can be removed with a `strings.Trim()`:

```
fmt.Println(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprintf("%08b", bs), "[]")) // prints 11111111 11111101
```

Comment: This was a really good solution, thanks for adding it! I selected it as the accepted answer. BTW; do the answer need the strings.Trim() part? I feel the answer would be more concise without it

Comment: well, i tried to make it clear that the `strings.Trim()` was an optional extra.

Comment: Don't mind me; it's still an excelent answer:-)

Answer (score 22):

Simplest way I have found:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    bs := []byte{0x00, 0xfd}
    for _, n := range(bs) {
        fmt.Printf("%08b ", n) // prints 00000000 11111101
    }
}
```

Playground with this code: https://go.dev/play/p/piJV_3OTHae

Comment: There's also `strconv.FormatUint` if you want the string, but same idea.

Comment: @JimB Do you have a playground with an example of `strconv.FormatUint` for printing binary?

Comment: OK, so it's a replacement for the `fmt.Printf`, I was hoping it was a replacement for the for-loop:-)

Answer (score 1):

Or use this simple version

```
func printAsBinary(bytes []byte) {

    for i := 0; i < len(bytes); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            zeroOrOne := bytes[i] >> (7 - j) & 1
            fmt.Printf("%c", '0'+zeroOrOne)
        }
        fmt.Print(" ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

[]byte{0, 1, 127, 255} --> 00000000 00000001 01111111 11111111
```